# XMLHttpRequest RESTful (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть образец функционала XMLHttpRequest https://gist.github.com/EtienneR/2f3ab345df502bd3d13e

Когда его запустил на nodejs (require("express")) возникла ошибка : 
" Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. "

есть решение ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ты должен на сервере разрешить кросс-доменные запроса с домена клиента
2. В заголовок запроса добавь поле `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` со значение `*`(или твой домен)
   Можешь посмотреть описание и примеры [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain).

Comment: Можно по пунктам "на пальцах" (с примером) объяснить то, что Вы написали. Я только начал изучать NODEJS и XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: По пункту 2. Синтаксис такой? xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');